# Ruby Cannot assert raised exception

Tags: ruby

i have a class as so....

```
module Test
 
  class Client
 
     def initialize(string_value,hash={})
     end

     def throw_exception
        raise "hi"
     end
   
   end
end
```

In my `rspec code` i have:

```
RSpec.describe Test::Client do
   it "can reach throw exception and raise exception" do
      @client = instance_double(Test::Client)
      expect{@client.throw_exception}.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
      @client.throw_exception
   end
end
```

When I run the test case, my result is:

```
expected RuntimeError, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<InstanceDouble(Test::Client) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :throw_exception with (no args)> with backtrace:
```

So I read online i need to pass the method in the stub, so I do this:

```
RSpec.describe Test::Client do
   it "can reach throw exception and raise exception" do
      @client = instance_double(Test::Client,:throw_exception)
      expect{@client.throw_exception}.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
      @client.throw_exception
   end
end
```

And now i get...

```
expected RuntimeError, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<InstanceDouble(Test::Client) :throw_exception> received unexpected message :throw_exception with (no args)> with backtrace:
```

I'm not quite sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are running your test on an instance_double, not on a real instance that has the method implemented. Just initialize a real instance and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any particular reason why you would be using an instance double here in the first place:

```
RSpec.describe Test::Client do
  subject(:client) { Test::Client.new("Foo") } 
  it "can reach throw exception and raise exception" do
    expect { client.throw_exception }.to raise_error("hi")
  end
end
```

If you really want to use an instance double you need to allow the call:

```
RSpec.describe Test::Client do
  subject(:client) { instance_double(Test::Client) } 
  before do
    allow(client).to receive(:throw_exception).and_call_original
  end

  it "can reach throw exception and raise exception" do
    expect { client.throw_exception }.to raise_error("hi")
  end
end
```